# Angular2 http get json issue

Tags: json, typescript, angular

Trying to display http json response in angular2 view. To get me started I have completed a specific tutorial for .NET core and Angular2 with Typescript. Everything worked fine, so I tried to modify it a bit but it looks I got stuck and can not find the answer. This is what I have so far.

wall.main.component.ts

```
import {Component, OnInit} from "angular2/core";
import {CORE_DIRECTIVES} from "angular2/src/common/directives/core_directives";
import {WallService} from "./wall.service";

@Component({
    selector: "wall",
    templateUrl: "app/components/wall/wall.main.html",
    providers: [WallService],
    directives: CORE_DIRECTIVES
})
export class WallComponent implements OnInit {
    data: any;

    constructor(private service: WallService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.get();
        console.log(this.data);
    }

    get() {
        this.service.get().subscribe((json: any) => {
            console.log(json);
            this.data = json;
        });
    }
}
```

wall.service.ts

```
import "rxjs/Rx"
import {Http} from "angular2/http";
import {Injectable} from "angular2/core";

@Injectable()
export class WallService {
    constructor(private http: Http) { }

    get() {
        return this.http.get("wall/getwallposts").map(response => response.json());
    }
}
```

wall.main.html

```
<wall>
    <p>{{data.Id}}</p>
    <p>{{data.Body}}</p>
</wall>
```

Html does not display data. The error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Id' of undefined in [{{data.Id}} in WallComponent@3:7]
```

Tried a lot of ways. Accessing as an array with the index data[0].Id, changing variable types, nothing. Also this console.log(json) works fine. I can see and read the object in the console, but the other one console.log(this.data) shows undefined, which I would expect to be the same. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On view when CD started, `data.Id` interpolation tries to evaluate, but `data` object isn't defined yet. So when it tried to access `Id` property from it, it throw an error.

```
<wall>
    <p>{{data?.Id}}</p>
    <p>{{data?.Body}}</p>
</wall>
```

Other thing I wanted to point out is, there is no meaning to have `wall` element again, as you are already rendering a `wall` component.(I know it is not gonna work, because we haven't provided it inside `directives` option of `Component`)

Comment: It seems that errors are gone but no data displayed

Comment: @DasBoot are you getting correct `data` printed in console?

Comment: Yes, but as I mentioned console.log(this.data); returns undefined while console.log(json); works fine and returns data correctly.

Comment: @DasBoot That is correct thing.. async call will return a data once that completed.. here `subscribe` is acting as a callback function which is calling after ajax gets completed.. could you paste a `data` here, I think you are getting data in array format.. or its an object?

Comment: looks like it is working. Seems that the ? sign fixed it already. Thank you

Comment: @DasBoot glad to know that.. Thanks :-)